# Can the port be set in the Maven payara-micro-maven-plugin to avoid "address already in use" running multiple instances?

Tags: java, maven-3, java-11, payara-micro

Downloaded generated microprofile/payara demo app from:

```
https://start.microprofile.io/
```

Starting first instance (demo-service-a) runs fine.

Starting separate instance (demo-service-b), getting...

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:461)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:453)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:227)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:80)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOBindingHandler.bindToChannelAndAddress(TCPNIOBindingHandler.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOBindingHandler.bind(TCPNIOBindingHandler.java:64)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:215)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:204)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.config.GenericGrizzlyListener.bindTransport(GenericGrizzlyListener.java:211)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.config.GenericGrizzlyListener.configure(GenericGrizzlyListener.java:339)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyProxy.initialize(GrizzlyProxy.java:126)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyService.createNetworkProxy(GrizzlyService.java:664)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyService.postConstruct(GrizzlyService.java:586)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:303)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:351)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:93)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$UpOneLevel.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:762)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
]]
```

Where I might modify the bind port for the second instance - so as to avoid the aformentioned exception?

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo-service-b</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <properties>
    <final.name>demo</final.name>
    <payaraVersion>5.194</payaraVersion>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.microprofile</groupId>
      <artifactId>microprofile</artifactId>
      <version>3.2</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>demo</finalName>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>payara-micro</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>fish.payara.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>payara-micro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>bundle</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <processId>1234</processId>
              <payaraVersion>${payaraVersion}</payaraVersion>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

I am using Java 11 and IDE Netbeans 11.1.

payara-micro-maven-plugin version: 1.0.1

microprofile version:  3.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure the used port inside the `configuration` section in your `pom.xml`.

Either specify a port, 8888 in this example:

```
<commandLineOptions>
    <option>
        <key>--port</key>
        <value>8888</value>
    </option>                       
</commandLineOptions>
```

Or use the autobind feature:

```
<commandLineOptions>
    <option>
        <key>--autobindhttp</key>
        <value>true</value>
    </option>                       
</commandLineOptions>
```

There are also autobind options for https (`--autobindssl`), to specify a range (`--autobindrange <number-of-ports>`) or to specify the HTTPS port (`--sslport <ssl-port-number>`). See here for reference: [Payara Micro command-line options](https://payara.gitbooks.io/payara-server/documentation/payara-micro/appendices/cmd-line-opts.html)

Comment: Hi Christoph - haven't been able to get the "commandLineOptions" tag to work in the config section of the plugin... --i.e., when I build w/ the plugin and then run "java -jar demo-microbundle.jar", it seems to have no effect(?).   --However, if I use that argument directly in the run command (As in:  "java -jar demo-microbundle.jar --port 8884"), it does work!   So, I'll mark/select your answer accordingly as it **close enough**!!!  :-)    --Found it a bit odd my question was down-voted.  Gee, I thought it was a legitimate one...Ha!.   -In any case, thank you very much, again!  :-)

Comment: Hi @sairn, thanks for that. :) Strange that the Maven-way does not work. Some time ago I used it that way, as far as I can remember. It is also mentioned in the current documentation here: https://docs.payara.fish/documentation/ecosystem/maven-plugin.html However, the most current version of the plugin seems to be 1.0.5. Maybe you can give that a shot. They also have some example POMs on that page. Perhaps you can check if there is an error in your POM that keeps the command line options from working.

Comment: As for the downvote: maybe it was due to some formatting "problems". At least that is what the edit suggests. ;) However, I have neutralized it with an upvote since I belive it was a valid question altogether and I understood the problem.

Comment: thx, Christoph!   --Definitely intend to check out the docs you cited to see if I can get it working that way too.   (And, hopefully, the microprofile.io guys - with help from Payara - can adjust the pom.xml's in their demo generated from their "Starter" page)